# Why caret use rf without having requested it

Tags: r, random-forest, caret

I am using caret by declaring multiple models among which there is NO random forest but finally it comes out in "mixedModel $ method" the "rf" method. How is it possible?

There the code (i use a public dataset):

```
mix_dataset_tra<-rock

TrainIndex <- createDataPartition(mix_dataset_tra$area, p=0.75, list= FALSE)
train<-mix_dataset_tra[TrainIndex,]
test<-mix_dataset_tra[-TrainIndex,]
rm(TrainIndex)

trc<- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", number=10,repeats=3) 
AlgoritmList<-c("relaxo","lasso")
mixedModel<-caret::train(area~., data=train, methodList=AlgoritmList, trControl=trc)

mixedModel$method
```

Comment: Hi Gaetano, and welcome to SO. I'm not sure I totally understand your question, but if you look at `?caret::train` you'll see that the default is `method = "rf"`, does that answer your question?

Comment: Thanks Michael. Why then continue to use the default model ("rf") and not lasso and ridge regression in this case? Is there any mistake in the way I wrote the code using "methdoList"? Thanks

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59181966/8400969

Comment: Seeing your other question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73113307/8400969

Comment: You might need to specify `library` or other details.

Comment: One more that might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46638416/8400969

Comment: I'm not sure this is going to be trivial... not sure what your use case is, but perhaps easier to hard-code for each model than writing something flexible. Here is some of the details on what it takes to feed a model to `caret::train`: https://topepo.github.io/caret/using-your-own-model-in-train.html

Comment: One more, perhaps most promising example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56884831/8400969

Comment: Does this answer your question? [caret Error: Model is not in caret's built-in libraryModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73112741/caret-error-model-is-not-in-carets-built-in-librarymodel)